# Linked List in C - Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am a beginner, learning how to make linked lists in C. Whenever I try to print out the list, the list prints out just fine but I always end up with a segmentation fault at the end.

When I use GDB backtrace, it points me to the line -> entry = *((*node).data); in the printContents function.

However I am not quite sure what's wrong with it.

Here is the linked list code:

```
void createEmptyLinkedList(LinkedList *inList) {
    inList = (LinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));

    (*inList).head = NULL;
    (*inList).tail = NULL;

    (*inList).size = 0; //Keeps track of size of list

    return;
} 
void insertAtStart(LinkedList *inList, JournalEntry *inValue) {
    LinkedListNode *newNode;
    int listSize = (*inList).size;

    newNode = (LinkedListNode*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedListNode));

    (*newNode).data = inValue;
    (*newNode).next = (*inList).head;
    (*inList).head = newNode;
    ((*inList).size)++;
    return;
}

void printContents(LinkedList *inList) {
    LinkedListNode *node;
    JournalEntry entry;

    node = (*inList).head;

    while (node != NULL) {

            entry = *((*node).data);

            printf("%04d-%02d-%02d: %s\n", entry.year, entry.month, entry.day, entry.text);

            /*Move node to the next node*/
            node = (*node).next;
    }
    printf("Done!");
    return;
}
//Free nodes recursively
void freeLinkedList(LinkedList *inList) {
    freeNode((*inList).head);
    free(inList);
    return;
}

void freeNode(LinkedListNode *node) {
    if (node != NULL) {
    freeNode((*node).next);
    free(node);
}
```

Here is the main function used to start the linked list:

```
int main() {
    LinkedList list;
    JournalEntry *value;
    char* textToEnter;

    value = (JournalEntry*)malloc(sizeof(JournalEntry));

    createEmptyLinkedList(&list);

    textToEnter = "Hello";
    (*value).day = 10;
    (*value).month = 5;
    (*value).year = 2010;
    strcpy((*value).text, textToEnter);
    insertAtStart(&list, value);

    printContents(&list);

    freeLinkedList(&list);
    return 0;
}
```

And just in case anyone needs it, here are the structs declared in the header file:

```
typedef struct LinkedListNode {
    JournalEntry *data;
    struct LinkedListNode *next;
} LinkedListNode;
typedef struct {
    LinkedListNode *head;
    LinkedListNode *tail;
    int size;
} LinkedList;
typedef struct {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    char text[1000];
} JournalEntry;
```

Comment: Not specifically related to your question, but just for future reference, anything of the form `(*foo).bar` can be rewritten as `foo->bar`.

Comment: Did you check if `data` has a valid value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything in C is passed by value, including pointers.  So, assigning to inList won't affect the value the caller has passed. Rather, you should be taking a pointer to a pointer if you want to do it this way:

```
void createEmptyLinkedList(LinkedList **inList) {
    *inList = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));

    (*inList)->head = NULL;
    (*inList)->tail = NULL;

    (*inList)->size = 0; //Keeps track of size of list

    return;
}
```

Without this, you're just working with an uninitialized pointer to hold your list. In your main code you also need to change it like:

```
LinkedList *list;
createEmptyLinkedList(&list);
```

Notice that list is declared as a pointer here.

Comment: Or just do remove the malloc() part, because that's what messed things up. Then just go to initialization part the way it is. Maybe except that ugly `(*inList).data` part.

Comment: @zubergu: Sure. That's also a valid solution. Although at that point I'd argue the function is somewhat misnamed (create vs init).

Comment: You're absolutely true.

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it, problem is you didn't decide whether `createEmptyLinkedList()` should allocate memory for your head, or you will do it in `main()` function.
And you did both.
In `main()`
you did `LinkedList list;` -- this part creates LinkedList structure.
Then you pass address of that structure to your function. And that's fine to this point.

In your `createEmptyLinkedList()` you have inList pointer pointing to list structure. And that's fine as well.

But now you mess things up and `malloc()` another LinkedList structure, making `inList` point to newly malloc'd structure.

Then you initialize you brand new LinkedList structure, return from `createEmptyLinkedList()` without changing `list` structure in `main()` because you initialized your newly `malloc'd` structure, **not list**.

You can fix it by deciding whether your `LinkedList` structure will be created in `main()` or `createEmptyLinkedList()`.
If you choose 2nd -- read above answer.
But if you choose 1st -- leave everything as it is and remove line in `createEmptyLinkedList()` that is responsible for malloc'ing.
Then, as **FatalError** suggested - more appriopriate name to your function would be **initializeEmptyLinkedList** because there is no **create** part anymore.